# How to access value from input tag BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, input, beautifulsoup

```
<input type="hidden" id="upload_box" newval="XYZ.com" />
```

I need to get that value inside newval. I tried this code but it's not working.

```
tagval = soup.find("input", attrs={"id" : "upload_box"})['newval']
print tagval
```

It gives `KeyError: 'newval'`

It's strange but this code is working for other fields which don't have link as value in them.

How to get that value?

Comment: Which version of BeautifulSoup are you running? It works for me on BS4.

Comment: I'm working with Python 2.7.9 and just upgraded to BS4. Still not working for me.

Comment: this should work for the tag as shown; have you verified that the tag looks like this in your `soup` object (as opposed to e.g. in a browser)?

Comment: Try checking the html code for that tag using View Source and not Inspect Element.